# Dell BIOS Update Date

Tags: boot, dell, bios, settings

Is there a way to gather information as to when a BIOS on a particular server has been updated?

I'm not looking for the BIOS release date, I'm looking for the date in which the bios was actually updated.

I suspect some people updating BIOSes in our environment but since we don't keep a maintained list of incoming/existing BIOSes its hard to tell if someone has changed it recently.

Comment: afaik, you could only determine this by checking the filesystem for the existence of update tools or images, and see when they were executed or accessed - unless cd or usb were used, then no. bios doesn't store a modified-date, only revision info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be in the DRAC system logs on the Dell. Have you checked there?

Comment: Look for iDRAC log entries similar to the following: `Updating firmware for Server BIOS 12G to version 2.2.2.` - `Successfully updated the Server BIOS 12G firmware to version 2.2.2.` - `Version change detected for BIOS firmware. Previous version:2.1.3, Current version:2.2.2`

Comment: You realize, of course, that it is fairly easy to clear the log out.  Thus this method is not necessarily foolproof.

Comment: Sure it isn't. But you'll see the date it was cleared.